# replace HTML content from associative array with jquery

Tags: jquery, associative-array

I want to apologize for my question but as i just began 1 day ago in jquery... it may sound a little bit stupid. 
i have an associative array with content :

```
var myContent = {
    'key1' : 'text1',
    'key2' : 'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia 
     dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...'
}
```

and a text in html :

```
<p>key1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin 
vestibulum est non nunc feugiat, ut hendrerit dolor semper. key2 Lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vestibulum est non nunc 
feugiat, ut hendrerit dolor semper. key1 and key2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vestibulum est non nunc feugiat, ut 
hendrerit dolor semper. </p>
```

I want to replace key1 & key2 by html like this :

```
<p><span data-content="text1">key1</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Proin vestibulum est non nunc feugiat, ut hendrerit dolor semper.
<span data-content="Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, 
consectetur, adipisci velit...">key2</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Proin vestibulum est non nunc feugiat, ut hendrerit 
dolor semper. etc.</p>
```

So i tried many things but i didn't get the expected result for example :

```
$.each(myContent ,function(key,value) {
    for ( i = 0; i <= Object.keys(myContent).length; i++ ) {
        var expr = new RegExp(key,'i');
         $("p").each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text();
            text = text.replace(expr, '<span data-note=""> '+ expr + ' </span>' );
            $(this).text(text);
        });
    }
});
```

it generates text and when i try to generate HTML i have error messages.. then it reproduces the span at least 3 or 4 times. 
I think you'll find all beginner mistakes we can imagine.

Thanks anyway for your help...

Answer (score 2):

Please change your javascript code to this.

```
  $.each(myContent, function(key, value) {
        $("p:contains('" + key + "')").html(function(_, html) {
            return html.split(key).join('<span data-content="' + value + '"> ' + key + ' </span>');
        });
    });
```

Jsfiddle Link https://jsfiddle.net/aanair08/uzwpp5hk/

Comment: it works fine ... i also found another solution longer than the one you propose ... thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace() method from the JavaScript String object...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var myContent = {
        'key1' : 'text1',
        'key2' : 'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...'
    }

    var newText = $('p').text();

    $.each(myContent, function(key,value) {
        newText = newText.replace(key,'<span data-content="' + value + '">' + key + '</span>');
    });

    $('p').html(newText);
});
```

Here you have a fiddle... https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/tqoh690L/

I hope it helps

Comment: it's really helpful even if i have to choose one solution. Anyway it helps me improving the way i can make it.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit less elegant than the previous solution made by A. Iglesias but it also works ...

```
$('p').each(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(myContent).length; i++) {
        var originalContent = this.innerHTML;
        pattern = new RegExp(Object.keys(myContent)[i], 'g');
        var newText = originalContent.replace(pattern, '<span data-note="' + myContent[Object.keys(myContent)[i]] + '">' + Object.keys(myContent)[i] + '</span>');
    if (originalContent !== newText) {
        this.innerHTML = newText;
    }
}
```

});